# Dropped some of the "sand" from my magnetic hour glass in my desktop case

Tags: desktop-computer, magnet

Earlier today my magnetic hourglass broke and some of the sand fell into my case. Nothing has happened yet and most of it seems to be sitting on top of the gpu. I am going to clean it soon but just wondering if there is any real chance of it doing damage to my computer if it gets into the wrong spot.

My hourglass is like the one in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0rdE5tKcvY

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest potential risks are the iron filings shorting a component or getting lodged in a mechanical part such as a fan. Whilst that may not have happened just yet, the fans may move them around, or they may attract to magnetic fields within the system.

I'd try and get them out as soon as possible. It's unlikely it's done any damage if you haven't noticed a problem (at least, yet), but it's not going to do it any good, that's for sure. I certainly wouldn't advise having it powered up until you've removed them.

Comment: And how would you get them out? Compressed air?

Comment: @TomBoehmerRastavious Compressed air, gently with the machine tipped so it'll fall *out* and not get blasted further in is likely to be the best bet. Hard to say without knowing how much and where it actually is.